# Remove Background of an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing, computer-vision

The code works fine for the images that are high resolution. But sometimes when the image's resolution is not good enough or background color matches the color in the image it jus can remove the background completely. Sometimes, leaves white patches in the removed bg images.
Below are the examples. On the left original images, on the right images with removed background images.

Input Image

[image]

Output image from the below code

[image]

Desired Output

[image]

On the right is the input images and on the right is the output images of the code which could remove the background completely.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Below is the code that describes the process used to remove background of the image using OpenCV.

```
def remove_background(img):
    #== Parameters =======================================================================
    BLUR = 5
    CANNY_THRESH_1 = 10
    CANNY_THRESH_2 = 100
    MASK_DILATE_ITER = 20
    MASK_ERODE_ITER = 20
    MASK_COLOR = (0.0,0.0,0.0) # In BGR format
    
    #== Processing =======================================================================
    
    #-- Read image -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    
    #-- Edge detection -------------------------------------------------------------------
    edges = cv2.Canny(gray, CANNY_THRESH_1, CANNY_THRESH_2)
    edges = cv2.dilate(edges, None)
    edges = cv2.erode(edges, None)
    
    #-- Find contours in edges, sort by area ---------------------------------------------
    contour_info = []
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    
    for c in contours:
        contour_info.append((
            c,
            cv2.isContourConvex(c),
            cv2.contourArea(c),
        ))
    contour_info = sorted(contour_info, key=lambda c: c[2], reverse=True)
    
    
    #-- Create empty mask, draw filled polygon on it corresponding to largest contour ----
    # Mask is black, polygon is white
    mask = np.zeros(edges.shape)
    for c in contour_info:
        cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, c[0], (255))
    # cv2.fillConvexPoly(mask, max_contour[0], (255))
    
    #-- Smooth mask, then blur it --------------------------------------------------------
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=MASK_DILATE_ITER)
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=MASK_ERODE_ITER)
    mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (BLUR, BLUR), 0)
    mask_stack = np.dstack([mask]*3)    # Create 3-channel alpha mask
    
    #-- Blend masked img into MASK_COLOR background --------------------------------------
    mask_stack  = mask_stack.astype('float32') / 255.0          # Use float matrices, 
    img         = img.astype('float32') / 255.0                 #  for easy blending
    
    masked = (mask_stack * img) + ((1 - mask_stack) * MASK_COLOR) # Blend
    masked = (masked * 255).astype('uint8')                     # Convert back to 8-bit 
    cv2.imwrite('img.png', masked)
```

Comment: I do not understand the lines on the right side that you say are after background is removed. Is that the issue or do you have the images reversed? Please clarify.

Comment: @fmw42 yes the background is removed but not successfully if you see the images on the right is the background removed? Yes. Is the background removed successfully ? No. In both images on the right, there are small white patches. and white color still exists in the background. What I want to do is to remove the background completely and be left with only the food item.

Comment: I still do not understand. Do you want to get rid of the bowls? Why are there black lines on the right side that are not there on the left side? Post and example of what you want to see.

Comment: @fmw42 if you check i have updated the question and added a picture of a salad in which the background is completely and efficiently removed. Thanks

Comment: @fmw42 The black lines come from the blending. The mask is blurred, most likely to get a smooth transition between object and background. For the high-res image, where the algorithm works, this doesn't occur, but for the smaller low-res images.

Comment: Can't reproduce the output corresponding to the high-res input image.

Comment: @HansHirse Yes exactly, doesnt work with low-res image. For The salad image I am not able to get that output from the above code but thats what I want. The sprite image's background is removed easily as i have updated.

Comment: @VineetSuryan can you help with this issue [Make edges of the image smoother](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507755/make-edges-of-the-image-smooth)? It has the same code as yours and you might be able to solve it.

Comment: Automatic background removal is a topic that has generally not been solved yet, so you probably won't be able to make it work for every image. There are several approaches where you add an interactive component by letting the user draw lines to determine background border, you might want to look into these.