# Make an image smoother with White Circled Background

Tags: python, image-processing

**I want this project to be Done in Python**

I have this mage , I want to make each image i upload like image below
[image: I have this mage , I want to make each image i upload like image below]

Each image should be Circled like this if some border is needed to make it Circle add border otherwise don't add any border and add gray background
[image: Each image should be Circled like this if some border is needed to make it Circle add border otherwise don't ad any border]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in Python OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Compute max dimension, offsets and center of input
- Create white image of max dimension plus padding
- Insert input image into center of white image
- Create gray background image of same dimension as white image
- Draw a black circle of diameter equal to max dimension in the center of gray background
- Blur the black circle to create the drop shadow
- Create a white circle of diameter equal to max dimension in center of black image
- Blend the image on white background with blurred black circle on background to form the result
- Save the result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image and get maximum dimension
img = cv2.imread("radio_skull.jpg")
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]
maxwh = max(ww,hh)
offx = (maxwh - ww) // 2
offy = (maxwh - hh) // 2
cx = maxwh // 2
cy = maxwh // 2
pad = 10
pad2 = 2*pad

# create white image of size maxwh plus 10 pixels padding all around
white = np.full((maxwh+pad2, maxwh+pad2, 3), (255,255,255), dtype=np.uint8)

# put input img into center of white image
img_white = white.copy()
img_white[offy+pad:offy+pad+hh, offx+pad:offx+pad+ww] = img

# create light gray background image with 10 pixel padding all around
bckgrnd = np.full((maxwh+pad2,maxwh+pad2,3), (192,192,192), dtype=np.uint8)

# create black circle on background image for drop shadow
cv2.circle(bckgrnd, (cx+pad,cy+pad), cx, (0,0,0), -1)

# blur black circle
bckgrnd = cv2.GaussianBlur(bckgrnd, (25,25), 0)

# create white circle on black background as mask
mask = np.zeros_like(img_white)
cv2.circle(mask, (cx+pad,cy+pad), cx, (255,255,255), -1)

# use mask to blend img_white and bckgrnd
img_white_circle = cv2.bitwise_and(img_white, mask)
bckgrnd_circle = cv2.bitwise_and(bckgrnd, 255-mask)
result = cv2.add(img_white_circle, bckgrnd_circle)

# write result to disk
cv2.imwrite("radio_skull_img_white.jpg", img_white)
cv2.imwrite("radio_skull_background.jpg", bckgrnd)
cv2.imwrite("radio_skull_mask.jpg", mask)
cv2.imwrite("radio_skull_img_white_circle.jpg", img_white_circle)
cv2.imwrite("radio_skull_bckgrnd_circle.jpg", bckgrnd_circle)
cv2.imwrite("radio_skull_result.jpg", result)

# display it
cv2.imshow("img_white", img_white)
cv2.imshow("bckgrnd", bckgrnd)
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("img_white_circle", img_white_circle)
cv2.imshow("bckgrnd_circle", bckgrnd_circle)
cv2.imshow("result", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Input on white background:

[image]

Blurred black circle on background:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Masked image on white:

[image]

Masked black circle:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: That's is so accurate Sir , Thank you !