# Cropping image and key points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I would like to crop an image with smooth edge (preferably using contours), and get key points in the middle. Any help is really appreciated.

Original image:

[image]

I have tried the code below

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img_ref = cv.imread('img.jpeg')
img1 = cv.cvtColor(img_ref, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img1_blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img1, (7, 7), cv.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# create mask
thresh, img1_edges1 = cv.threshold(img1_blur, 100, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# remove noise
img1_edges2 = cv.dilate(img1_edges1, (3, 3), iterations=1)
img1_edges3 = cv.morphologyEx(img1_edges2, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, (7, 7))
mask_img = cv.morphologyEx(img1_edges3, cv.MORPH_OPEN, (7, 7))

# mask the original image
img1_masked = cv.bitwise_and(img_ref, img_ref, mask=mask_img)

# initiate ORB and find the keypoints with SIFT
orb = cv.ORB_create(200)
kp1, des1 = orb.detectAndCompute(img1_masked, None)

img1kp = cv.drawKeypoints(img1_masked, kp1, None, flags=None)

cv.imshow('mask', mask_img)
cv.imshow('key_point', img1kp)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Mask result (it's not clean, and the edges are not smooth):

[image: mask]

I have used contour for the mask, but it did not work.

Key points (all around the edges):

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do a Gaussian blur and then stretch the dynamic range to achieve antialiasing. See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507755/make-edges-of-the-image-smooth/63550942#63550942

Answer (score 0):

For cropping this approach has worked with some of my images

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# load image
img_ref = cv2.imread('wing_image.tif')


# convert to gray
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_ref, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


# threshold
img_thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# blur threshold image
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_thresh, (0,0), sigmaX=3, sigmaY=3, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)

# stretch so that 255 -> 255 and 127.5 -> 0
img_stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(img_blur, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# threshold again
img_thresh2 = cv2.threshold(img_stretch, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get external contour
cnts = cv2.findContours(img_thresh2, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

maxcontour = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, default=0)


# draw white filled contour on black background

contour = np.zeros_like(img_thresh2, dtype=np.uint8)
contour.fill(0)
mask1 = cv2.drawContours(contour, [maxcontour], 0, 255, -1)


# dilate mask for dark border
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (20,20))
mask2 = cv2.morphologyEx(mask1, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)


# apply mask to img
mask3 = cv2.bitwise_not(mask2)
img_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(img_ref, img_ref, mask=mask3)
```

And getting Keypoints (not around the edges) has been solved yet. I very much appreciate your help